# How to maintain Publish Status of already published after DB refresh

Tags: publishing, web8.5

My question is similar as following question, 
[Publish State](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/15301/web-8-restoring-db-from-prod-to-dev-and-the-publish-status) But I am getting 2013 Prod and restore and upgrade.
If I want to DB refresh before GO live from 2013 Prod, My Publishing State will be over written. Without republishing do we have any other alternatives?
We have a long gap between UAT and Go-Live, Its very difficult to do content port the large no of items.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Prasanna

Comment: we already have an accepted answer to the other question (with alternatives as well). In Short, publish states are part of the content manager database. Can you explain how your question is different from the other one? Maybe add how you are publishing (TPM or legacy), if you are republishing your content or remediation of it with with publish states. Suggest that you add a detailed approach and we can add alternatives. Cheers.

Comment: We are using TPM, In other question they are trying to map different environments where TCM IDS will be different and Topology is different, in My case I am just going to remap my Topology so only missing part is Publishing Status

Answer (score 3):

I am still unable to comprehend your question clearly but based on your comments, it looks like you are looking to replace the Publish States from a restored database.

If you do NOT have to republish your entire content, you can try to use the `Convert-TcmPublishStates` from [HERE](https://community.sdl.com/product-groups/sdl-tridion-dx/tridion-sites/tridion-developer/b/weblog/posts/sdl-web-8-migrating-from-old-to-new-style-publishing-part-1-of-3-the-cmdlet). I suggest review the options available and test it in a lower environment before trying it out in production.

If you have to republish your content due to other framework updates involved, you will have to republish the content once the restore is completed again for production.

Hope it helps!